# The best way to show AppStore and GooglePlayStore Apps metrics in Data Studio

Tags: google-play, app-store, looker-studio

I need to add in Data Studio metrics my apps in Play Store and AppStore, like 'number of installations'.
I searched for free connectors in Data Studio, but didn't find any. Apps metrics should update automatically. Are there any ready-made solutions for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no ready-made solution.  However, Play Store supports [exporting data to Google Cloud Storage](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870#export).

You can surely connect to this data using Data Studio (using the standard connector for GCS) or even create a dataset using BigQuery.

For AppStore you'll probably need a hand-made solution.

Answer (score 0):

A friend and I had the same problem so we built this [Data Studio connector](https://easyappreports.com/?utm_source=stack-overflow&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=stack-overflow-post). It enables you to bring data from both App Store and Google Play without having to deal with CSVs.

And you can always build yours if you want to, using [Google App Scripts](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector)